# Imported Mysql Tables into CoreData: How to get a Left Join without using relationships?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have imported a mysql from a web app into my iOS app.  This database is designed specifically without using foreign keys.

I need to do a Left-Join but I can't figure out how to do this in iOS core-data without using a relationship.

Is there not a way to just get two tables data using a Data.id == Item.id like syntax in a 
NSPredicate???

----------EDITED----------

To put it more specifically I want to take a Data entity with and match the item attribute with the Entity Item'S entity code attribute.  Any "objects" that don't have a match should not be included.

Just like a left join..... Ya feel me?

I am stumped.

Help 
Thanks.

Comment: How would the two "tables" (they are `Entities` actually) know about each other if they did not have a relationship? Same principle as with your girlfriend... **Don't be afraid of a relationship!**

Comment: lol.... I am not afraid of them but god... all I want to do is what I described above but there is no easy way it seems to accomplish this in core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask "*is there no easy way in core data*"?
Turns out, it is much easier in core data than in SQL.

Simply make entity `Item` a relationship of entity `Data`. Your predicate could then be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item = %@", itemObject];
```

What could be easier than that??

Assumptions: relationship is one-to-one, name of relationship is `item`, `itemObject` is a managed object of type `Item`.

*For the record: you are actually not even dealing with a table, because Core Data is an object graph and not a database. You will find many discussions on this here on SOF.*

Comment: Confusing.  The problem with relationships is that they don't let you specify connections via your own attributes.  Only the default one that are made for you behind the scenes????!!!!!!

Comment: Its the  main reason why I can't get my head around this.  I don't want to use ids I want to use data.item and item.code as a relationship.  In other words when I search data entity using that relationship i should be able to pull out item.code or  item.* as I please.

Comment: You are a victim of "database think". Forget the foreign keys, they are dealt with behind the scenes. You are not concerned with how the entities (they are not tables) identify each other. Just set up the relationship, it's really much simpler. Create a one-to-one relationship of entity `Data`, called `item` and linked to entity `Item`, and back a relationship `data` in `Item` linking to entity `Data`.

Comment: The reason for this is I am importing data from a mysql table. the are being saved row by row.  Because the import program is done row by row I cannot insert objects with preexisting relationships.  This is my problem.  And my questions is again how can I get data out of item using a conditions statement like data.item == item.code without relationships or if it can be done with relationships how????

Comment: You can and should import and create the relationships. I do not understand your objections. "Row by row" is even better, it would work exactly as stated.  --- That being said, you can do **two** fetches and fetch the other entity by `code` when you need it. It would be hugely inefficient and very bad programming, but if you insist... :-(

Comment: Ok but when I try to do it the way you stated it give me 0 results.... the reason it has no way of connecting the object to each other.  How can a relationship work if there is no connection via data.

Comment: In other words how can I specify how to connect to the data not just where.

Comment: So basically how can I say give me the data objects and item object that have a matching attribute of data.item and item.code.... why is that so hard to grasp.... The thing is I Do care how the data is linked.  I need to know how its being linked in order to properly set up my import from mysql.